# ejecutar funcion automática dentro de la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, base-de-datos

Buen dia, en mi base de datos tengo una tabla de eventos que tiene una columna para "fin de evento" (Datetime), y quiero que en ese fecha exacta se elimine automáticamente de mi base ese evento.¿como lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos respuestas posibles:

1. En tu servidor crea un CRON JOB que ejecute tu programa que borra los eventos de la fecha actual hacia atras.
2. En tu programa principal (ej. el menu) ejecuta el programa que borra los eventos.

Desde mi punto de vista seria mas sencillo crear un CRON JOB y que se ejecute despues de la medianoche (digamos a la una de la mañana) ya que por la noche hay menor flujo de usuarios.

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.